# How To Modify New Sub Blog Immediately When Super Administrator Creates It?

Tags: multisite, customization

I want to trigger a function in a plugin when a new sub-blog is created in a multisite set up of WordPress. Is it possible? If so, to which action/filter should I hook?

The motivation here is to modify the new sub-blog blog it has a preset arrangment of settings, theme, plugin options, plugin activations, content set up, etc.

If there aren't action/hooks for this purpose are there any other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: How about use a plugin that does this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U guess you can use the **activate_blog** hook

Comment: I am not able to find any such hook in the wordpress source code. Could you point out which file it is in?

Comment: [`wp-admin/ms-edit.php` line 402](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-admin/ms-edit.php#L402)

Comment: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wpmu_new_blog