# How to run scripts when a new blog is created in Buddypress?

Tags: buddypress, mysql, actions

I'd like to insert some mysql data into every new blog that's created on my buddypress system. How can I hook up to the newly created blog data? ID, for example, would allow me to insert it right from the PHP. Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see: [How To Modify New Sub Blog Immediately When Super Administrator Creates It?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4039/how-to-modify-new-sub-blog-immediately-when-super-administrator-creates-it)

The code I wanted to post I unfortunately could not post beacause "body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 62367" so ... the following filters are handy (from WordPressMU plugin for site admin to set defaults for new blogs, Deanna Schneider) :

```
function set_blog_defaults($blog_id, $user_id)
{
    global $wp_rewrite, $wpdb, $current_site;
    switch_to_blog($blog_id);
            // do stuff
}

// When a new blog is created, set the options 
add_action('wpmu_new_blog', array(&$cets_wpmubd, 'set_blog_defaults'), 100, 2);

?>
```